# Win 10 Enterprise hangs on reboot, but shuts down within 2 seconds

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze, reboot

Recently, I can't seem to restart properly anymore.

Upon restart, it hangs on the "Restarting" screen with the spinning dots for ~5-10 minutes before the usual restart process happens.
My mice still works, as if I click anywhere, the screen goes black, though with no effect on restart time.
Shutdown is as snappy as ever, takes less than 2 seconds before I hear my fans "click" off.

I've done several power cycles, turned off autostart programs, unplugged all peripherals, updated bios + chipset to no avail.
Any ideas? I have a decent system, Ryzen + NVME drive. And it was fine a while (couple weeks?) ago?

`edit:`
seems the fast shutdown was caused by the `Turn on fast startup` feature.
Upon unticking that, the shutdown time now matches restart time, also hanging on the "Shutting down" loading screen for several minutes.

Comment: Check for applications that are not politely quitting. See https://windows101tricks.com/app-preventing-shutdown-windows-10/. Also do a malware scan with an alternate tool (e.g. Malwarebytes).

Comment: Event viewer is your friend.